Typescript - specify generic types of another generic
Is it possible to somehow specify the generic parameters of a generic type?
I am trying to create a fully typed api url builder, which will set correct types on my data models based on the specified options for the url.
Question was edited (see history for previous versions):
/**
 * A base data model class
 */
class BaseModel<T extends Record<string, any>> {
    private data: T = {} as T

    getAttribute<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
        return this.data[key]
    }
}

/**
 * A derived data model class, which includes custom methods
 */
class CustomModel extends BaseModel<{ foo: string, bar: number }> {
    someMethod() { }
}

type GetAttributes<T extends BaseModel<any>> = T extends BaseModel<infer A> ? A : never
type PickAndNullifyOthers<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? T[P] : null
}
type GetModelFromBuilder<T> = T extends Builder<infer M> ? M : never

/**
 * A URL builder class, which allows to pick only specific attributes from a model
 */
class Builder<T extends BaseModel<any>> {
    pickOnly<K extends keyof GetAttributes<T>>(key: K): Builder<BaseModel<PickAndNullifyOthers<GetAttributes<T>, K>>> {
        return {} as any
    }
}


Usage

const wrapper = new Builder<CustomModel>()
    .pickOnly('foo')    // we picked only the `foo` attribute, so others should be `null`

const model = {} as GetModelFromBuilder<typeof wrapper>

const fooResult = model.getAttribute('foo')
const barResult = model.getAttribute('bar')

// the types of `CustomModel` getters are lost because it is typed as `BaseModel`
model.someMethod() // error

The problem I ran into is that when I try to get the new type of the data model with the adjusted attributes, it shows up as BaseModel and I'd like it to be CustomModel as in the generic T: class Builder<T extends BaseModel<any>>

could you provide full code at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?

@AlexanderNenashev I edited the original question since the link was too long for comments

• Please also [edit] to put all the code as plaintext so that it's a [mre]. (A link is nice but it's not enough by itself; we can't ask people to navigate away from here to see the code. Or let me know if you give me permission to do so (it's not clear that anyone but you has the rights to that code). Thanks! • You can't do what you're asking for directly; that would require ms/TS#1213). There might be alternative approaches but so far I haven't really been able to follow your code; you might want to simplify further for a [mre].

(see prev comment) Yeah, this code is probably too complicated to be a good [mre]. It doesn't look like the part that's supposed to already work is actually working (you end up inferring Record<string, any> for TEmbeds no matter what). As a first step I'd make sure your type params are explicitly represented properly, as shown in this playground link. But even this is a bit intractable for me... you might want to just [edit] this way down to something like this. It's still not possible to solve directly but it's at least easy to state.

@jcalz I tried to simplify the example as much as possible & added it to the question as well, along with an updated playground link. Thank you so much for your responses!

It's still quite complicated. I do wish we had started with the simpler version from my last link, since I believe it captures the basic idea without needing dozens of lines of code. But: what do you expect modelType.someOtherEmbed to be? If you expect it to be null then modelType is not a UserModel, so we'd need to hear exactly what type you expect it to be.

@jcalz You're right. Simplified it even further and edited the question (hopefully for the last time  sorry it took me so long to simplify it..)

Given your new code: again, you really don't want it to be a CustomModel because then getAttribute('bar') won't be null. I think maybe you're looking for something like this, given the example code now. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Oh I get it. Well, this is close to what I wanted to achieve, however, I would like the getAttribute method to be protected and only used in classes extending the BaseModel in custom getters. Basically, something like this.

I really doesn't seem that you actually want a CustomModel then, since a CustomModel's bar property is of type number. You can see that for yourself in your code. TypeScript types don't become generic automatically; it's not like you can ask TypeScript to re-analyze get bar()'s body in light of a different BaseModel argument. It's just number. So what exactly are you trying to achieve here? Can you express the intended type of model in terms of the types you already have? If not, I don't see how we can automate it for you. How should I proceed here?

I'm not sure what you mean by expressing the intended type in terms of the types that we have.
I would like the getters to re-evaluate the underlying types of the attributes and behave the same way as .getAttribute() did in your example.
Would maybe adding a generic to the CustomModel help?
something like class CustomModel<A extends Partial<CustomModelAttributes> = {}> extends BaseModel<CustomModelAttributes & A>

Making CustomModel generic would at least make it possible for a CustomModel<A> to have a different type for its bar property depending on A. But it doesn't help Builder unless it anticipates CustomModel and therefore has a list of all possible models in advance. You can't say "whatever T is, it's also generic." That would require ms/TS#1213 (see my very first comment) and is not part of the language.  Shall I write an answer saying it's impossible?

Thank you very much for your explanation. Yes, please write the answer and I'll accept it.

This isn't currently possible as asked. The big stumbling block is that TypeScript doesn't have a direct way to represent higher kinded types as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#1213.  First, in order to even get close, you'd need CustomModel to be generic so that sometimes its bar property can be null (right now it is always number):
class CustomModel<T extends { foo: any, bar: any }> extends BaseModel<T> {
    someMethod() { }

    get foo() {
        return this.getAttribute('foo')
    }

    get bar() {
        return this.getAttribute('bar')
    }
}

const m = new CustomModel<{ foo: string, bar: number }>();
m.bar // number
const m2 = new CustomModel<{ foo: string, bar: null }>();
m2.bar // null

And your hope is that Builder would be generic in some type which is itself generic, sort of like this:
// not valid TS, don't try this:
declare class Builder<B<~> extends BaseModel<~>, T> {
    pickOnly<K extends keyof T>(
      key: K
    ): Builder<B, PickAndNullifyOthers<T, K>>;
    getModel(): B<T>
}

const wrapper = new Builder<CustomModel, { foo: string, bar: number }>()
    .pickOnly('foo')    

const model = wrapper.getModel();
const fooResult = model.foo // string
const barResult = model.bar // null

But TypeScript doesn't support this. That's what microsoft/TypeScript#1213 is about.
TypeScript only has generic types (e.g., B will be resolved to some type like type B = CustomModel<{foo: string, bar: number}>), not generic type functions (e.g., B would be resolved to some type function like type B<T> = CustomModel<T>).

There are various ways to try to encode generic type functions in TypeScript, some of which are mentioned in microsoft/TypeScript#1213, but they usually involve a bunch of boilerplate and/or "registering" ahead of time the things you'd like to treat as higher order generics.  In some sense, Builder would need to know about all possible generic model.  For example:
interface ModelRegistry<T> { }
type Apply<B extends keyof ModelRegistry<T>, T> = ModelRegistry<T>[B]

And then when you define CustomModel you can merge an appropriate entry for it:
class CustomModel<T extends { foo: any, bar: any }> extends BaseModel<T> {⋯}

interface ModelRegistry<T> { CustomModel: CustomModel<Extract<T, { foo: any; bar: any; }>> }


class AnotherModel<T extends { baz: any }> extends BaseModel<T> {⋯}

interface ModelRegistry<T> { AnotherModel: AnotherModel<Extract<T, { baz: any }>> }

And then Builder can be written in terms of the registered model name and its attribute type:
declare class Builder<B extends keyof ModelRegistry<T>, T extends Record<string, any>> {
    pickOnly<K extends keyof T>(
        key: K
    ): Builder<B, PickAndNullifyOthers<T, K>>;
    getModel(): Apply<B, T>
}

const wrapper = new Builder<"CustomModel", { foo: string, bar: number }>()
    .pickOnly('foo')

const model = wrapper.getModel();
const fooResult = model.foo // string
const barResult = model.bar // null

This sort of looks like what you're asking for, but the boilerplate for registering models might not be what you want. There are other approaches mentioned in microsoft/TypeScript#1213, and some people claim they are less tedious, so possibly some approach like this meets your needs. Without native higher kinded types, though, it's always going to look like a workaround.
Playground link to code

Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation! I appreciate it a lot!
